# Не работает SQLite после сборки проекта Java

Tags: java, sqlite, maven

Доброго времени суток! Делаю проект в IDEA с использованием SQLite. В среде разработки проект вполне рабочий, однако после сборки на maven файл базы данных создается и на этом все заканчивается. Весит она 0 байт, при открытии через SqliteBrowser не находит ни 1 таблицы соответственно.

Вот файл **pom.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MoneyManager</groupId>
    <artifactId>MoneyManager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>
                            src/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                        </manifestFile>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            <packageName>MoneyManager</packageName>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.toedter/jcalendar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toedter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

вот код **Java**:

```
    package util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Created by user on 23.08.16.
 */
public class DbHelper {

    private Connection connection;
    private String URL = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";
    private String DRIVER = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    private static DbHelper ourInstance = new DbHelper();

    public static DbHelper getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private DbHelper() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            createTables();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }

    private void createTables()
    {
        try {
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("./src/main/java/createbase/database.sql"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (is.available() > 0)
            {
                char x = (char) is.read();
                sb.append(x);
                if(x == ';')
                {
                    st.execute(String.valueOf(sb));
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                }
            }
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ошибки сыпет какие нибудь?

Comment: Смущает путь `./src/main/java/createbase/database.sql`. Разве в "спакованном" варианте у вас есть данная дирректория/файл?

Comment: Ошибок нет. А по поводу пути - закинул все файлы в том числе и этот скрипт в папку resources. Не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте исользовать `getClass().getResourceAsStream` вместо  `Files.newInputStream`. Ну и параметром путь(к примеру если просто в ресурсах, без подпапок то будет просто `getClass().getResourceAsStream("database.sql")`